# How to begin with a BOM when using the PhoneGap FileWriter

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I try to write a *.csv file with the PhoneGap FileWriter. It works fine and the output is correct formated in UTF-8. The problem is that some reader like Excel expect a BOM (byte-order-marker) to detect UTF-8.

How could I add this BOM at the beginning of my file?

Answer (score 0):

Just start your output with

writer.write("\xEF\xBB\xBF");

before you append your csv content.

Comment: This does not work. I got this hex codes at the beginning of my file: c3 af c2 bb c2 bf

Answer (score 0):

I start with

```
writer.write("\uFEFF");
```

It's documented here:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

It works!