# Writing a CSV file: displaying �Â� characters

Tags: javascript, php, csv, cordova

Using phonegap I am creating an app that can export a csv file. I am doing this by using a file writer (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter).

The problem is when I open the exported .csv file using *OpenOffice.org* it is showing this characters: �Â� before a degree symbol (°).
Here are the details:

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="&#176;C"> &#176;C </option>
<select>
```

**Value being saved in the database:**

```
ID | temperature | temperature_unit
--- ------------- -----------------
1  |   36        |       Â°C
```

**PHP**

```
while($row = $STH->fetch())
    $row['temperature_unit'] = html_entity_decode($row['temperature_unit']);
    $row_set[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

**Javascript (shortened)**

```
//data = json_encoded $row_set
var datatoexport = JSON.parse(data)

var content = "Temperature \n";

for(var x in datatoexport) {
    content += datatoexport[x].temperature + " " + datatoexport[x].temperature_unit;
}

//write content to file
writer.write(content);
writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
    alert("File exported");
};
```

**Result (csv file opened in openoffice.org application)**

```
Temperature
-----------
36 �Â�°C
```

**EDIT: AJAX and PHP code to save data to database (shortened)**

ajax

```
assetinfo = {temp:"35",temp_unit:"°C"}

$.post(serverURL + 'API/save.php',
    {
        temperature: assetinfo.temp,
        temp_unit: assetinfo.temp_unit
    },
    function(data) {
        alert("saved");
        }
   });
```

php

```
$temp = $_REQUEST['temperature'];
$temp_unit = $_REQUEST['temp_unit'];

$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO bearing_table (temperature, temperature_unit) VALUES (:temp, :temp_unit)");
$STH->bindParam(':temp', $temp);
$STH->bindParam(':temp_unit', $temp_unit);
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: This is an encoding problem, somewhere you wrote the UTF-8 (°) as `LATIN1`. There is already the wrong value in your database. Is your database column encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: @mudasobwa the table's collation is currently set to "latin1_swedish_ci", what should i set it to?

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding problem, somewhere you wrote the UTF-8 (°) as LATIN1. There is already the wrong value in your database.

Set the table’s column collation to `utf8_general_ci` and don’t forget to update database with correct value “°C”.

**UPD**

- HTML should use the UTF-8 encoding:

  `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
- In ajax request there might be `contentType: "charset=utf-8",` explicitly specified.
- Try to ptint out the `$_REQUEST['temp_unit']` value to see if the value is corrupted before saving into the database.

**UPD2**

- As a hotfix I could suggest to call [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) on `_REQUEST['temp_unit']`, but this sounds lame.
- BTW, the problem might be in [internal MySQL encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php). Try to [set the client charset explicitly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

Comment: I tried changing the collation of the column to what you said but it still saves "Â°C"

Comment: 1. As far as I understood, this is a “static“ value, save it using `phpMySqlAdmin` or like. 2. Whether there is a problem with saving data to the database, please provide the code you use to write the value to database. 3. Is your page is set to be UTF-8 encoded? Try to change `"&#176;C"` to explicit `°C` and see, what’s being printed out.

Comment: I dont know why but it still saves "Â°C". 1) HTML pages are already using utf-8 encoding. 2) i changed my ajax call from $.post to $.ajax and added contentType: "charset=utf-8". 3) $_REQUEST['temp_unit'] outputs "°C".

Comment: correction: $_REQUEST['temp_unit'] outputs "Â°C" when echoed in PHP. I used javascript's alert and the data is coming from the php thru ajax that's why it showed as "°C".  What seems to be the problem in PHP?

Comment: As a hotfix I could suggest to call [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) on `_REQUEST['temp_unit']`, but this sounds lame. Would you mind to check if it is working?

Comment: I tried to use utf8_encode and this is the result: "Ã‚Â°C". I tried utf8_decode and it showed the degree symbol without the "Ã". I'll try to save this to the database, if it works then my problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to hear. Sorry for messing de-/en- coding, will update the answer.

Comment: It is now saving into the database properly, without extra characters BUT when i am getting the data from the database it is returning null. Should I change the PHP code? `$row['temperature_unit'] = html_entity_decode($row['temperature_unit']);`

Comment: `html_entity_decode` should not affect the UTF somehow. Try to [set the client encoding in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)?

Comment: Now it's returning as "\u00b0C". and it's null when it writes to the csv file.

Comment: Aha. The last chance: the writer you use should accept the parameter setting an encoding, right? Specify `UTF-8` there.

Comment: "Text is encoded as UTF-8 before being written to the filesystem." (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter). What's weird is it's displaying normal on "Kingsoft Office" application on the tablet, but when the file is opened in Openoffice.org or MS Excel it's not displaying properly. Does this have something to do with BOM?

Comment: @clintgh I must admit I ran out of ideas :( What’s evident for me, the value in the database is now correct, the ajax sends the correct value and the CSV writer _receives_ the correct value. Hence, it’s a CSV writer now who corrupts it. Would you mind to try another CSV writer?

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, I appreciate your help. It seems that the READER is the problem not the WRITER. I followed this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989092/how-to-begin-with-a-bom-when-using-the-phonegap-filewriter I tried adding `writer.write("\uFEFF");` for BOM, and i also added "charset=utf8" in my script tags to make sure. The result: It is now showing properly on Excel and Kingsoft Office. The only problem now is "Openoffice.org". So I guess the problem is with the reader (Openoffice.org itself), and I don't think I have to solve this anymore. heh

Comment: Since that is the `csv` file, I would suggest you to open it by plain text editor and see, what’s happening there.